# Angular update array printed via *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

How could I update array of elements which is printed via `*ngFor`? I've set inputs with two-way bindings but it doesn't seem to change the original array. Also tried to set `trackBy` but didn't help.

**Parent component template**

```
<ul>
  <app-skill-item
    *ngFor="let skill of skills; trackBy: trackByFn"
    [skill]="skill" (edited)="updateSkills()"></app-skill-item>
</ul>
```

In component skills described as `skills: Observable<string[]>;` and fetched from FireBase. I need to update that array and push it back to update document.

**Child chomponent**

```
<li class="lead" *ngIf="!isEditing" (click)="editStart()">
  {{ skill }}
</li>
<li class="lead" *ngIf="isEditing" (click)="editStart()">
  <input [(ngModel)]="skill" type="text" (blur)="editEnd()">
</li>
```

**How I get values**

```
constructor() {
this.skillService.getSkills(this.db).subscribe(names => this.skills = names.name);
}
```

**Service**

```
getSkills(db) {
    return db.collection('about').doc('skills').valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far.

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: My guess is simply that the observabel returned by this.skillService.getSkills(this.db) only emits once. What happens if you replace `this.skills = names.name` by `{ console.log('emitting'); this.skills = names.name; }`? How many times is 'emitting' being printed? What is the code of the getSkills() method?

Comment: The problem is that data binding on each component from `*ngFor` doesn't update corresponding values in `skills`

Comment: Please, answer the questions you're being asked. Note that your description is already a problem: you say that `skills`is an Observable<string[]>, but you iterate on it, although Observable is not iterable, and you initialize it with `this.skills = names.name`, inside a subscribe to valueChanges, so it is probably an Array<string>, not an observable.

Comment: I've been following a guide and since it works and WebStorm doesn't show any type errors I assume it's ok. (also it properly prints out values)

Comment: @JBNizet emitted once (since FireBase isn't updated)

Comment: So the problem has absolutely nothing to do with ngFor not printing an updated array. The problem is that the array is never updated in the first place. How and where do you update the array?

Comment: As I told it's updated from `*ngFor` printed elements (at least I hoped it would so). I have an input for each array value with two-way binding. But updating input's value doesn't update the corresponding value in the array

Comment: Yes, that can't work. Assigning a new value to a string as you're doing can't possibly replace the old string with the new one in the array that it came from. I.e. what you're doing is equivalent to `const array = ['a', 'b', 'c']; const str = array[0]; str = 'z';`. That won't change anything to the array. You need something somewhere that actually modifies the array: `array[0] = 'z'`.

Comment: I thought that `*ngFor` binds values to array so tried to update it

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Please, post that I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never modifying anything in the array. What your code does is basically equivalent to

```
// input binding with [skill]="skill"
childComponent.skill = parentComponent.skills[index];

// ngModel binding
childComponent.skill = "some new entered value";
```

And that doesn't change anything in the array.

You need to change your design to actually change the value in the array, i.e. have something that does

```
parentComponent.skills[index] = "some new entered value";
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are working with an observable though, you will not be able to edit it. So what you could/should do is subscribe to it, get the first value, and copy it.

In your class/component

```
constructor() {
     this.skillService.getSkills(this.db).pipe(first()).subscribe(names => this.skills = names.name);
}
```

The reason why I'm suggesting to only take the first value (by piping the first operator), is because we can not necessarily change the observable values, we do not want the observable to emit a new value and overwrite our newly assigned value with something different. The first pipe will automatically unsubscribe from the observable and prevent that from happening. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Changed nothing